# Server file sharing on separate locations

Tags: networking, server

I am looking for a bit of advice on network shared folders but not on a local network.

I have two servers one of them is hosted with digital ocean and the other is a web server hosted with 1&1, my 1&1 server has unlimited storage so I currently have a load of movies stored on it but I want to be able to link them over to the second server where I have Plex hosted, I am wondering if anyone here knows of a way to share network files using this method. I do have a static IP on my digital ocean server and a domain name on the other so hopefully I can point a program towards those so that it can link them up to an extent.

Does anyone know of an application that I can setup to link these two areas